# Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError with firefox headless on aarch64 host

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, arm64, geckodriver, headless

env :
host : aarch64 GNU/Linux [5.4.17-2136.320.7.1.el8uek.aarch64]
selenium : Mozilla Firefox 102.12.0esr
gecodriver : 0.33.0 (2023-04-03)
execution mode : headless

### issue :

[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     *** You are running in headless mode.
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     (firefox:1941703): Gtk-WARNING **: 06:08:38.001: Locale not supported by C library.
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          Using the fallback 'C' locale.
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server (t=1.19267) [GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server (t=1.19267) |[1][GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL initialize failed (t=1.19271) [GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL initialize failed
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     1690783718933        Marionette      INFO    Marionette enabled
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     1690783718938        Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 37009
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Read port: 37009
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     1690783719160        RemoteAgent     WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     console.error: Region.jsm: "Error fetching region" (new TypeError("NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.", ""))
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     console.error: Region.jsm: "Failed to fetch region" (new Error("NO_RESULT", "resource://gre/modules/Region.jsm", 419))
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server (t=1.19267) |[1][GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL initialize failed (t=1.19271) |[2][GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt (t=1.96393) [GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
[DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
[LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager]

Is there anything i need to take care , in order to run selenium in headless mode, on firefox browser, on  aarch64 machine?

### manually run command: firefox --headless

*** You are running in headless mode.

### (firefox:1952235): Gtk-WARNING **: 07:08:29.202: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server (t=0.517705) [GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server (t=0.517705) |[1][GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL initialize failed (t=0.517746) [GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL initialize failed
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag

excepcitng a working command.